# groupValues only returns last occurrence of repeating pattern

Tags: regex, kotlin

```
println(Regex("(A|B)+").matchEntire("AB")!!.groupValues)
```

prints `[AB, B]` but I would have expected the result to be `[AB, A, B]`.

- Is this behaviour expected?
- Is there a way to obtain `[AB, A, B]`?

Comment: Yes, expected. But as for `AB`, `A` and `B`, it is a bit not that easy. How about `println(Regex("(?:(A)|(B))+").matchEntire("AB")!!.groupValues)`?

Comment: Regex groups cannot capture an arbitrary number of matches, they only "keep" the last match. (There are some regex engines that can do this, but _generally_ regex doesn't support it.) You might be better off without regex, but it's hard to say without knowing what your program is doing.

Comment: @Rawing the actual regex is much more complex so I'd rather stick to that. I'll probably use Wiktor's solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Feel free to turn that into an answer.

Comment: @assylias: But what if you have `123abc456def` and then you will use `(?:(\d+)|(\p{L}+))+` ... and you will only get `[123abc456def, 456, def]`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xaSTVJ/1).

Comment: @assylias: I added the answer, but also I explained the limitation there. If you need to handle the strings like I mentioned in some specific way, please let me know, and it would be best if you could also provide *real life* examples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your answer - I see the limitation indeed and based on that I have taken a different approach where I just capture the whole repeating group `some_other_stuff_((A|B)+)_some_more_stuff` and split it manually in code. It works well so all good for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you get is expected. `(A|B)+` matches and captures `A`, places the match value into Group 1 buffer and then captures `B` (as the `+` matches one or more times) and *places the value into Group 1 **re-writing** the `A` inside*.

So, the only way to get what you need is *capturing* both `A` or `B`, but it is not that easy.

See

```
println(Regex("(?:(A)|(B))+").matchEntire("AB")!!.groupValue‌s)
```

See the [Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/CEVP47515).

It outputs `[AB, A, B]`, as the the whole string matches the regex, the value is added as the first item, the Capture 1 is added as the second item, and Capture 2 is the third item.

But if you have a longer string like `123abc456def` and you have `(?:(\d+)|(\p{L}+))+`, you [will lose all the captures but last](https://regex101.com/r/xaSTVJ/1). So, for `123abc456def` input, you will get `[123abc456def, 456, def]`.

However, you should provide more details in case you need to match such strings.